# Наследование unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс который наследуется от базового.Нужно вызвать метод наследника в базовом классе.Я думаю,что неправильно объявляю ссылку на наследника в базовом(private ClassName name).

```
       public class ParadoxUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private JustGenerate justGenerate;

    private void Start()
    {        
        justGenerate.Reloading();
    }
}

        public class JustGenerate:ParadoxUI
{
    public void Reloading()
    {
        int luckyNumber = Random.Range(0, 3);
        switch (luckyNumber)
        {
            case 0:
                dr1 = true;
                dr2 = false;
                dr3 = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                dr1 = false;
                dr2 = true;
                dr3 = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                dr1 = false;
                dr2 = false;
                dr3 = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: все может быть, но мы этого не узнаем, пока вы не покажете код.

Comment: tym32167, вот код

Comment: Вы не можете вызывать приватные методы в наследниках. Чтобы наследники могли пользоваться методами, методы должны быть защищенным или публичными.

Comment: Я не могу вызвать метод наследника в базовом классе из-за ошибки NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ParadoxUI.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Paradox/ParadoxUI.cs:36)

Answer (score 0):

В классе `ParadoxUI` есть поле типа `JustGenerate` которое наследуется от `ParadoxUI`... WTF? Змея съела свой хвост.

```
public class MyClassA : MonoBehaviour {

    protected virtual void MethodA () {
        Debug.Log("MyClassA - MethodA");
    }

    protected virtual void MethodB () {
        Debug.Log("MyClassA - MethodB");
    }
}

public class MyClassB : MyClassA {

    private void Start () {
        this.MethodA(); // this не обязательно
        MethodB();
        base.MethodA();
    }

    protected override void MethodA () {
        Debug.Log("MyClassB - MethodA");
    }
}
```

Log:

```
MyClassB - MethodA
MyClassA - MethodB
MyClassA - MethodA
```

Comment: Start не вызывается